# No "referenced libraries" in VS Code Java project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I imported a Java project into Code that was originally developed in Eclipse. At first, the entire "Java Projects" section in the explorer would not appear, but I did a "Clean Java language server workspace" and it appeared. However, "Referenced Libraries" does not appear:

[image]

I am not sure why this is the case. When I manually added the jars I wanted to the `.classpath` file, the "Referenced Libraries" appeared but said "Read-only." Further, doing a workspace clean removed these from the `.classpath` file, and the "Referenced Libraries" section disappeared again. Am I missing something? What can I do to get "Referenced Libraries" back?

Comment: There's something different between Eclipse and VS Code, you can try to create a java project and add referenced libraries in VS Code. Compare to experience it. Refer to [Create a project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_create-a-project) and [Add a jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it editing the .classpath file directly. After creating a "lib" directory aside "src" and "bin", I wrote a new line like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/yourlibrary.jar">
```

After that, I opened VScode and it recognized the referenced library.

Comment: Right, I mentioned doing that in my original post, but that (a) it makes them "Read-only" (whatever that means in this context) and (b) if you clean the workspace later it might remove those entries from `.classpath`

Answer (score 1):

Remove .classpath and .project files from the project folder. Then put your referenced library (for ex. jar file) file into lib folder. After you restart vscode it will be fixed.